# ruby get part of a hash redis

Tags: ruby, json

I have this type of hash stored in variable `foo`

```
{:name=>"bobby", :data=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]}
```

when I try `foo[:data]` I get `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

How do I get the 2d array?

EDIT

This is the entire code:

```
redis = Redis.new
  redis.set "foo", {name: "bobby", :data => [
    [1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]
  ]}
  foo = redis.get "foo"
  puts foo[:data][0]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `{:name=>"bobby", :data=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]}[:data] #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]`

Comment: I know it seems really weird... I don't know why I cannot access this, this is the result of a redis.get command. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redis.get` returns a string, not a hash. This string is JSON representation of the hash. Try:

```
require 'json'
foo = JSON.parse(redis.get "foo")
puts foo['data']
```

Comment: When I do that i get `gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in 'parse': 757: unexpected token` on the parse line

Comment: Please do: `p redis.get('foo')` and paste the result.

Comment: `"{:name=>\"bobby\", :data=>[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]}"`

Comment: AH, this is not JSON, this is ruby has notation. How is this value stored in redis? DO you have any control over it?

Comment: yeah, I am calling `.to_json` when I save. Thanks!

Comment: @Killerpixler - Sorry I've missed the set. :P